# Longest contiguous subsequence without repeated numbers

Tags: algorithm, sequence

I have the following task:

> Find the length of the longest consecutive subsequence such that all numbers in it
>   are unique.

Now if I do not assume that elements of my sequence are not from some fixed alphabet but they can be, for example, arbitrary numbers, is this task still solvable in linear time?

Comment: hint: there are 10 unique digits.  seems like 10 is the maxim length with no repeated numbers (assuming number = digit)

Comment: @DwB Well, there are 16 unique digits in hexadecimal number system, and 95 in pentanonagesimal. But the question is about numbers and not digits. It's stated explicitly in the question the numbers could be arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved using two pointers and a set of elements. Let `i` be the head pointer and `j` be the tail pointer, both starting at zero.

For each index `i`, add the element `S[i]`, where `S` is the sequence to the set if the element does not exist in the set. If it does exist, then increment `j` until `S[i] == S[j-1]`, removing each element from the set. At the end of the loop, store the max size of the element set.

This is linear time because both pointers iterate through the sequence at most `n` times and `contains()`, `remove()`, and `add()` on a hash set are amortized constant time.

```
int longestUnique(int[] S) {
  HashSet<Integer> elements = new HashSet<Integer>();
  int longest = 0;
  for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < S.length; i++) {
    if (elements.contains(S[i])) {
      do {
        elements.remove(S[j]);
      } while (S[j++] != S[i]);
    }
    elements.add(S[i]);
    longest = Math.max(longest, i - j + 1);
  }
  return longest;
}
```

Comment: Hey buddy. Small question. After getting rid of all the elements from the `HashSet`, don't you want to reset the `i` pointer to j_initial + 1? I was thinking about a case like `1,2,3,4,5,1,6,7`. When you encounter the second `1`, you have a maxLength of 6. If you start from the second `1`, you will find a sequence of size 3. Whereas, starting from 2 gives a size of 7.

Comment: No you don't need to, as `j` is incremented to the point where it no longer includes the first instance of `1`. The code I supplied produces 7 for `1,2,3,4,5,1,6,7`.

Comment: Ah! Missed that. Thanks for the clarification